# Case Else Statement from different tables

Tags: object, universe

I am trying to retrieve a name based on a certain type of claim.  Would seem easy enough, but it's not working for me.  I am working with 2 main tables, `claim` and `exposure`, and a `contactname` table.  Each `claim` can have multiple `exposures`, but each `exposure` can have only one `claim`.  Both tables contain a `nameID` field - `claim.nameID` and `exposure.nameID`.  The `nameID` correlates to `ContactName` table.

`Contact  Name`

`ID  Name`
`111 Jim`
`222 Bob`
`333 John`
`444 Sam`
`555 Walt`

Normally, each `claim` can have multiple `exposures` and the `exposures` on a `claim` can have the same name or different names. The name `ids` are found on the `exposure`.

`The exposure.nameID joins ContactName.ID`

`Claim  claim.nameID    ExposureNo  exposure.nameID Name`
`A      null            1           111             Jim`
`A      null            2           222             Bob`
`A      null            3           333             John`
`B      null            1           444             Sam`
`B      null            2           444             Sam`

Workers comp claims are different.  Each workers comp claim can have multiple exposures, but all the exposures have the same name.  Since the exposures on a claim have the same name, the name ids are found, not on the exposure table, but the claim table.  Go figure…  The claim.nameID joins ContactName.ID AS ClaimContactName.

`Claim  claim.nameID    ExposureNo  exposure.nameID Name`
`C      111             1           null            Jim`
`C      111             2           null            Jim`
`C      111             3           null            Jim`
`D      555             1           null            Walt`
`D      555             2           null            Walt`

I can get the names for non workers comp `claims` and can get the names for `workers comp claims`.  However, when I put the 2 queries together, I don’t get any results.

```
Select
CASE WHEN @Select(Claim\Policy Type) = 'Workers'' Compensation' THEN
CASE WHEN ClaimContact.Name IS NULL AND ClaimContact.Name.FirstName IS NULL THEN ClaimContact.LastName
WHEN ClaimContact.Name IS NOT NULL THEN ClaimContact.Name
ELSE ClaimContact.FirstName + Space(1) + ClaimContact.LastName END
ELSE
CASE WHEN Contact.Name IS NULL AND Contact.FirstName IS NULL THEN Contact.LastName 
WHEN Contact.Name IS NOT NULL THEN Contact.Name
ELSE Contact.FirstName + Space(1) + Contact.LastName END
END
```

Haven’t done much of this, but could really use the help to figure this out.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: What flavor and Version of Universe is this? As far as I know Universe SQL doesn't accept CASE WHEN syntax, so I assume this is mistagged or you are using something that is interacting with Universe.

Answer (score 0):

This was for an SAP Universe using Information Design  Tool.  I ended up creating a derived table that gave me exactly what I needed, including learning something new along the way.